# How do I get total count of result set to appear in every record of output?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, oracle11g, analytics

Using Oracle 11g

How can I write query to include a 4th column which displays the total rows returned?

I'm having technical difficulties posting a question
[as noted here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197468/where-can-i-get-more-information-about-my-submission-error) As soon as this posts, I'll continue with my edit.

Comment: So you want the max value or the total rows?

Comment: You understood exactly what I wanted. Yes, the 4th column returns the same value, total records in query, as part of the result set. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the window function:

```
SELECT  col1, col2, col3, COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_rows
FROM    mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

If you had meant the total **so far** then:

```
select  c1, c2, c3, 
        count(*) over (order by c1 range unbounded preceding) as total_rows
from    mytable
order by c1
```

This will get a result like:

```
C1 C2 C3 TOTAL_ROWS
A  B  C  1
A  B  D  2
B  D  E  3
...
```

Comment: Tony, thanks for the additional information about using the analytic count(). When I tried your suggestion here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53e2e/9, I get slightly different results.

Comment: But I could achive the same results using row_number() here.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53e2e/10.